# Applications requiring JRE not starting

Tags: 14.04, kernel, updates, java

When I first started my computer this morning, I started getting successive `System program problem detected` alerts. This is after a software update last night. Now my IDEs (Intellij, Android Studio) completely refuse to even open and trying to start them results in even more `System program problem detected` alerts.

I've diagnosed the problem. Here's the output of `sudo ls -l /var/crash/`:

```
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 kernoops whoopsie 1666 Aug 16 11:34 linux-image-3.13.0-155-generic.101926.crash
-rw-r--r-- 1 kernoops whoopsie 1716 Aug 16 11:43 linux-image-3.13.0-155-generic.104879.crash
-rw-r--r-- 1 kernoops whoopsie 1763 Aug 16 11:53 linux-image-3.13.0-155-generic.108790.crash
```

And here's the output when I `cat` one of those files, they all have the same content:

```
ProblemType: KernelOops
Annotation: Your system might become unstable now and might need to be restarted.
Date: Thu Aug 16 11:53:40 2018
Failure: oops
OopsText:
 BUG: Bad page map in process java  pte:80003ffffe17c225 pmd:6638a067
 addr:00007f2174c62000 vm_flags:08000071 anon_vma:          (null) mapping:          (null) index:7f2174c62
 CPU: 1 PID: 4917 Comm: java Tainted: G    B D    OX 3.13.0-155-generic #205-Ubuntu
 Hardware name: HP HP ProBook 450 G3/8101, BIOS N78 Ver. 01.05 12/02/2015
  0000000000000000 ffff8801d74b7a98 ffffffff8173983f 00007f2174c62000
  ffff8801d750ecc0 ffff8801d74b7ae8 ffffffff8117e374 80003ffffe17c225
  000000006638a067 00000007f2174c62 ffff88006638a310 ffff8801d74b7c58
 Call Trace:
  [<ffffffff8173983f>] dump_stack+0x64/0x80
  [<ffffffff8117e374>] print_bad_pte+0x1a4/0x250
  [<ffffffff8117f6ae>] vm_normal_page+0x6e/0x80
  [<ffffffff8117faa6>] unmap_page_range+0x3e6/0x830
  [<ffffffff8117ff71>] unmap_single_vma+0x81/0xf0
  [<ffffffff81181019>] unmap_vmas+0x49/0x90
  [<ffffffff8118a05c>] exit_mmap+0x9c/0x170
  [<ffffffff81118ee3>] ? __delayacct_add_tsk+0x153/0x170
  [<ffffffff8106a43c>] mmput+0x5c/0x120
  [<ffffffff8106fda4>] do_exit+0x264/0xa60
  [<ffffffff8109553a>] ? hrtimer_cancel+0x1a/0x30
  [<ffffffff810e0bb2>] ? futex_wait+0x1b2/0x290
  [<ffffffff8107061f>] do_group_exit+0x3f/0xb0
  [<ffffffff81080ba0>] get_signal_to_deliver+0x1d0/0x700
  [<ffffffff81014458>] do_signal+0x48/0xa30
  [<ffffffff810b92e6>] ? rwsem_wake+0x46/0x50
  [<ffffffff8137fb97>] ? call_rwsem_wake+0x17/0x30
  [<ffffffff81014ea9>] do_notify_resume+0x69/0xb0
  [<ffffffff8174ad70>] int_signal+0x12/0x17

Package: linux-image-3.13.0-155-generic 3.13.0-155.205
SourcePackage: linux
Tags: kernel-oops
Uname: Linux 3.13.0-155-generic x86_64
```

What does that even mean? It appears to me that the hint is in the `Comm: java Tainted: G`, but I'm not sure what steps to take from there.

Kindly advise.

Comment: Had to pull the same move (revert to 153), caught me by surprise (& kneecapped a bunch of production machines depending on Java)...not the most excellent start to my Thursday morning. Tracking things here: - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1787127 anyone else have any intel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a temporary fix, you can also boot your system with a previous kernel image if you don't have the habit to remove them.
In my case RESTART + hit the ESC key sent me to boot menu, select advanced options then select for instance the kernel image 153

Comment: Yes. This is what I did on the GRUB menu. In my case, the ESC key didn't work, neither did the right SHIFT key. I got into GRUB with the left SHIFT key. Many, many thanks, Andrei. Now my IDEs are opening.

Answer (score 5):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1787191
Seems a bug with the linux image, try revert to 153